# Documentation for Lock.__enter__() and Condition.__enter__()

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I'm trying to find where the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods of threading objects are documented for Python 2.7. The [main documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#condition-objects) on the topic has nothing of sort. Is this documented at all?

Is it, perhaps, so obvious what they should do, that I'm asking a nonsensical question? It's certainly not obvious to me. In my understanding, `__enter__` should acquire a lock, and `__exit__` should release it, but lock acquisition comes with optional parameters (blocking / non-blocking), so it's a bit ambiguous, at least to myself.

Comment: Did you see [this](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement)?

Comment: @BrenBarn No idea how I missed this..... long day, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [BrenBarn in the first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427416/brenbarn), the documentation does mention how to use locks with `with` statements [here](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement), which is implicit documentation for `__enter__` and `__exit__` ([see `with` statment context managers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)).

Note: The documentation linked by BrenBarn was documentation for Python 2.7, the latest (at the moment of writing for Python 3.10) can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement).